# zoom_changed triggering repeatedly on page load

Tags: google-maps, google-api

Using the Google Maps API, I've got two listeners in my `initMap()` function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function(e) {
    var searchType=location.search.split('=').pop();                
    MAPSEARCH.MY.searchOnLoc(false, searchType);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function(e) {
    var searchType=location.search.split('=').pop();
    MAPSEARCH.MY.searchOnLoc(false, searchType);
});
```

The first one works fine, but the second (`zoom_changed`) triggers several times while the page is loading, causing all kinds of chaos. How can I prevent this?

For testing purposes, I've tried changing to `bounds_changed` but it also triggers an extra time when the page is loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else causing what you describe. Just loading a map doesn't trigger a zoom change as you can see in the below example.

```js
function initialize() {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.2,6.17);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControl: true
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {

      alert('Zoom Changed');
    });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: You are right, I had a map resize triggering at one point that I think was causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to prevent the `zoom_changed` listener from loading until the map has finished loading:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function (e) {
        // var eventListener = google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, "bounds_changed", function () {
        var searchType = location.search.split('=').pop();
        MAPSEARCH.MY.searchOnLoc(false, searchType);
        // });
    });
})
```